# Reason why am I getting results querying a column with Data actually in another column, using like '%text%'

Tags: sql, blob, firebird

With Firebird 2.5.8, and a table with a dozen of blob fields, I have this weird behavior querying this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE BLOBFIELD4 LIKE '%SOMETEXT%'
```

and I get results though `SOMETEXT` is actually in a different column and not in `BLOBFIELD4` (happens with every blob column).

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you cant find ```%SOMETEXT%``` in BLOBFIELD4?  I think you might.

Comment: can there be "sometext" in small letters not caps? also, did you try `where blobfiled4 containing 'sometext'` - largely the same but looks more direct and thus less fragile than comples LIKE-syntax ? also, do you really hard-code search constant into SQL query instead of using parameters? may it be that you only THINK you passed `SOMETEXT` to the query but actually the server got empty string there? Use TraceAPI and see how your query looks server-side (you may take *FBProfiler* from *SourceForge* if you don't like console utilities like *fbtracemgr*)

Comment: 100% sur, plus result is exactly the same if i try `WHERE BLOBFIELD5 LIKE '%SOMETEXT%' `

Comment: i checked using fbtracemgr, nothing wrong from my point of view.
`sometext` is a part of a rtf string

Comment: This is either a bug in Firebird, or your expectation is wrong (eg the data is different than you think), but we can't rule out either without a reproducible example. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `sometext is a part of a rtf string` RTF like HTML has two levles, the "user content" you can see in some words processor applciaton, and the underlying "programming language" so to say, the lower level syntax constructs that make RTF formatting and such, and described in RTF Specifications. Using `LIKE` you search on the lower level, inside RTF specificatons syntax, not only in user content (maybe not in user content at all, if it gets hex-escaped). So if you think you only look for user content you might confuse yourself. Also, i wonder what should one row ever have 5+ RTF BLOB columns...

Comment: surely, aware of that.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/lxwotdr889gbfpb/TESTBLOBR.FDB/file
This is a sample db. Query: select * from comm where com1 like '%f4le dans 2 ans%' , the data are actually in COL2

Comment: Checking with DBeaver, I see the search term in `com1`, so my findings corroborate those of Arioch 'The.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the data. I made few fast tests using latest **IB Expert** with **Firebird 2.5.5**  (what i had on hands).

It seems that you actually have much more data, than you might think you have.

*First of all - it is a bad, dangerous practice to keep text data in columns marked as `CHARSET NONE` ! Make sure that your columns are marked with some reasonable charset, like Windows 1250 or UTF8 or something. And also that the very CONNECTION of your all applicationa (including development tools) to the database server also has some explicitly defined character set that suits your textual data.

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Or, if you want those BLOBs be seen as binary - then explitly create them as `SUB_TYPE BINARY` not `SUB_TYPE TEXT`*

However, here is the simple script to run on your database.

```
alter table comm
add    NF_VC    VARCHAR(4000) CHARACTER SET UTF8,
add    NF_BL    BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 4096 CHARACTER SET UTF8
```

then

```
update comm
set nf_vc = '**' || com1 || '**'
```

then

```
update comm
set nf_bl = '@@' || nf_vc || '@@'
```

*Notice, i intentionally force Firebird to do conversion BLOB -> VARCHAR -> BLOB.
Just to be on a safe side.*

Now check some data.

```
 select id_comm, nf_vc
 from comm where
 nf_vc containing 'f4le dans 2 ans'
```

and

```
 select id_comm, nf_bl
 from comm where
 nf_bl containing 'f4le dans 2 ans'
```

What do you see now?

[image] [image]

On the first picture we see that very mystery - the line is selected, but we can not see your search pattern in it, the *"f4le dans 2 ans"*. 
BUT !!!
Can you see the marks, the double asterisks, the `**` ?
Yes, you can, in the beginning! But you can not see them in the ending!!!
That means, you DO NOT see the whole text, but only some first part of it!

On the second picture - you see the very same row ID=854392, but re-converted back to BLOB and additionally marked with `@@` at both ends.

Can you see the marks on both start and end?
Can you see your search pattern?

Yes and yes - if you look at the grid row (white).
No and no - if you look and the tooltip (yellow).

So, again, the data you search for - it DOES exist. But you just fail to see it for some reason.

Now, when may be a typical reason the string is not displayed completely?
It can be the zero-value byte (or several bytes, UNICODE codepoint), the way `C` language marks the end of line, the custom that is vastly used in Windows and many libraries and programs. Or maybe some other unusual value (EOF, EOT, -1, etc), that makes those programs you use falsely detect the end of the text where it did not actually ended yet.

Look at the two screenshots again, where is that, that lines start to differ? it is after `\viewkind4 ... \par}` and before `pard`. Notice the weird anomaly! that said `pard` should start with reversed slash - `\` - to be a vaild RTF command. But it is instead prepended with something invisible, something blank. What can it be?...

Let us go back to your original query in your comments.

*Also, it is bad practice to put important details into comments! They are hard to find there for any person, that was not tracking the story from the very start. And the more comments added, the harder it gets. The proper avenue for you would have been to EDIT the question adding the new data into the quesiton body, and then adding a comment (for notification sake) saying the question was edited. Please, in future, add new data that way.*

```
select id_comm, COM1
from comm where
COM1 containing 'f4le dans 2 ans'
```

On the first glance our fishing ended with nothing, we see the text that does not have your pattern, ending at that very `\par}`.

[image]

But is it so? Switch into binary view, and....

[image]

Voila! What is there before the found-lost-found-again `pard`? there is that very **ZERO BYTE** i talked about earlier.

So, what did happenned, to wrap it up.

1. Firebird is correct, the data is found because the data is really there, in the BLOBs.
2. Your applications, reading the data, are not correct. Being confused with zero byte they show you only part of data, not all of data.
3. Your application, writing the data, might be not correct. Or the data itself.

How did that zero byte ended there? Why RTF structure was corrupt, lacking the reversed slash before `pard`? Was data size, you passed to the server when inserting that data, larger than it should had been, passing some garbage after a meaningful data? Was data size correct, but the data contents corrupt before inserting?

Something is fishy there. I do not think RTF Specifications explicitly prohibits zero byte, but having it is very untypical, because it triggers bugs like this in way too many applications and libraries.

*P.S. the design of the table having MANY columns with BLOB types seems poor.
"wide" tables often lead to problems in future development and maintenance.
While it is not the essense of your quesiton, but please do think about remaking this table into a narrow one, and save your data as a number of one-BLOB rows.
It will give you some fixed added work now, but probably would save you from a snowballing problems in future.*

Comment: RTF should be considered a binary format, not a text format, so using `BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT` for RTF is actually an incorrect choice. See also http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/rtf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format (eg 7-bit ASCII usage includes control characters, images can be include as binary data)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel we create RTF files in `windows 1251` 8-bit codepage and they work okay, without 'hex substitutions. Images also go as hex dumps, textual. Albeit specs mention binary form - i do not remember that being described in any details and i never saw it used. Also, isn't there `CDATA` in xml? But who would say XML is not text format?